Migrating or copying libraries from one pypiserver to another
There is a slightly old pypiserver that has been in use for some time and already hosts quite a few libraries.
I have decided to deploy a new instance with the latest version of pypiserver and a more updated AMI.
My question now is, what are the ways to migrate or copy the libraries hosted by the current pypiserver to the new one?
scp could be an option? or is there a tool that downloads the libraries from the current instance and uploads them to the new one?
